# How to set the border for a WPF DataGrid Row which is currently having the focus

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I want to set the border for a DataGrid Row which is currently having the focus. But not the seleced row because when the Multi selection is enabled for the datagrid then there is a chance that multiple rows can be selected.

I need a solution in XAML

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, you should mark the answers that answered your questions as such.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to `DataGridRow`'s style (either using Resources, or by setting `DataGrid.RowStyle`):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi svick,
I have already tried this, but the problem here is if i keep the focus on a row through tab then i m getting the border but if i tabe once again then focus goes to the cell, here i m losing the border though still it remains a current row. Hope this is clear

Comment: Perhaps triggering on the row's `IsSelected` property rather than the `IsFocused` property would work?

Answer (score 1):

Try IsKeyboardFocusWithin Property

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```